# Domain name at GoDaddy in not being linked to site hosted at Webhostingpad?

Tags: web-hosting

I just purchased the domain name at GoDaddy
and I wanted to link it to my WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM
hosting account.

This is what I set in my nameservers:

Nameservers:  (Last update 11/23/2011)

NS1.WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM 
NS2.WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM

[image]

but formatron.net still not being linked to my site at WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you done anything at webhostingpad.com to make sure they know about your domain?

Comment: How long did you wait before asking this? (See response from @Jigar_Tank)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not worry. DNS propagation generally takes 24-48 hours. And also make sure that you have added newly registered domain as an addon domain to your hosting account.

Comment: I think I forgot this -> "make sure that you have added newly registered domain as an addon domain to your hosting account"

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with the entries. I am also having the domain at godaddy and hosting at webhostingpad. It took some hours to be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm 100% agree with above explanation. The DNS will resolve 24-48 hours. If you still cant access your domain, you need to contact your hosting provider or please check whether you have pointed to right name server. :)

Comment: You should avoid referencing things like "above" in the answer area. The order others see them in is not necessarily the same *you're* seeing them in.